# Input data for this dataset to be feed into keras for training

Tags: machine-learning, classification, keras, preprocessing, numpy

Suppose I have 3 csv files which forms the dataset for training a machine learning model in Keras.

file1.csv

```
Name, X1,       X2,         X3
Joe,  1.16,                 1.00,                   1.11
Joe,  1.19,                 1.11,                   1.17
Joe,  1.17,                 1.13,                   1.16
```

file2.csv

```
Name, X1,       X2,         X3
Jack,   1.81,               1.23,                   1.15
Jack,   1.34,               1.53,                   1.87
Jack,   1.35,               1.64,                   1.75
```

file3.csv

```
Name, X1,       X2,         X3
Bo,     1.42,               1.64,                   1.43
Bo,     1.35,               1.53,                   1.32
Bo,     1.46,               1.64,                   1.53
```

Based on the data, I will classify whether the person has good or bad performance. For the data above, Joe has good performance while the rest have bad performance.

In keras, the above dataset will be transformed into numpy ndarrays `X_train` and `Y_train` to be fed into `model.fit()` like below;

```
model.fit(X_train, 
          Y_train, 
          nb_epoch=5, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_split=0.1)
```

I am confused over how `X_train` and `Y_train` should look like. What should be the shape of `X_train` and `Y_train`?

Suppose I have the following dataframes read from the csv files.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1.csv)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2.csv)
df3 = pd.read_csv(file3.csv)
```

How should I use these dataframes to get `X_train` and `Y_train`?

I am using python v3, keras with tensorflow.

Comment: Your data is a little confusing. Why does each person appear on multiple rows? Is each a measure of how they performed at a different time? When you say Joe performed well, do you mean you have a single output for the entire file1? (as opposed to one output per row) Finally I would suggest renaming your input variables to X1, X2, and X3. Calling them Performance1 etc is confusing because your ouput is also "Performance"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have renamed the inputs to X1,X2,X3 as you suggested. There is a single output for an entire file. Classification of good/bad performance is based on a single file contents. My confusion arises from how to shape the input (many dimensions) to feed into a keras model.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps:

1. The CSVs need to be merged and munged into [tidy data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) form. Pandas and DataFrames are the most common choice for those operations.
2. The resulting dataframe needs to be converted to a NumPy array. The text needs to be encoded as numerical values. One option is one-hot encoding.